# ROS_ROOT Problem

Tags: ros-diamondback, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I accidentally tweaked something "export ROS_ROOT=$PWD:$ROS_ROOT" into several directories, into /diamondback and /unstable directories. Where should it be located? I mean a standard ROS_ROOT. BTW, I want to point to the diamondback instead of unstable. Hopefully someone could guide me..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9145/ros_root-problem/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-02-20

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-21**:
Please don't put [SOLVED] in the title.  Also, don't mark every question as a community wiki, there is no reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally this command "source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash" saved me :-)

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-21**:
The check mark is below the thumbs up/thumbs down.  Here is an example: [http://imgur.com/mqRSE](https://imgur.com/mqRSE)  Please don't put SOLVED in the title of your post.  Thank you.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-21**:
I've tried both, and for the check mark or tick, it was complaining "Sorry, you cannot accept or unaccept your own answer to your own question"

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-21**:
Please try again. Not the thumbs up, but the check mark. This question still shows up as "unanswered", wasting people's time.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-21**:
Unfortunately, I could not tick my because it was complaining "Sorry, you cannot vote for your own post". I just wrote as [SOLVED] in the title, instead ..

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-21**:
There should be a check mark under the thumbs up/thumbs down.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-21**:
How to mark it? is it by clicking thumbs up?

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-02-21**:
If the issue is solved, mark one (can be your own) of the answers "the-best-one", for the question not to appear unanswered any more, please. Glad you made it :).